# Non-nullable instance field ''" must be initialized

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning flutter and trying to integrate API with it and I am getting some kind of error can anyone look and told what I am doing wrong here.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   Future<News> _newsModel; //getting error here 1*
  @override
  Future<void> initState() async {
    super.initState();
    var _newsModel = await API_Manager().getNews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("News App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _newsModel,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return (ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                );
              }));
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1*) compiler is giving this error "Non-nullable instance field '_newsModel' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'".

I have also tried by giving the late the error goes from the Editor but when the app runs it comes again. I am trying to get some news from the API and show them in the UI

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the `_newsModel` field has not been initialized. if you want to initialize the field later you must mark the field with the `late` keyword.

From your code, you are not initialize the field, but you declare new variable named `_newsModel` on `initState`. Try removing var keyword

```dart
Future<void> initState() async {
  super.initState();
  _newsModel = await API_Manager().getNews();
}
```